# How to measure Firefox's startup time?

Tags: firefox, time, benchmark

I would like to measure how much time it takes for some softwares to start.

I know the command `time` but in the case of firefox (iceweasel for me on Debian), this command prints only the time I let firefox open. If I launch:

```
$ time iceweasel www.google.com
```

I will have a startup time only after I closed firefox and this time will only indicate how long I left firefox opened. For example:

```
real    0m50.565s
user    0m4.276s
sys 0m0.248s
```

How can I know exactly how much firefox need to start?

Comment: Define "start". Is it when it opens its first window, when it will first respond to mouse clicks, when it finishes loading the web site, etc.

Comment: @derobert By "start" I mean to see the window. In fact, I don't really care, I just want a exact way of measuring the "startup" (whatever it is) to be able to do some tests (i.e. removing some addons and see if there is a improvement).

Comment: You could also try this extension: [about:startup](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/about-startup/).

Answer (score 6):

This is hacky and unscriptable.

Firefox can run javascript via command line like so:

```
firefox "javascript:alert(Date.now())"
```

That will open Firefox and run javascript that pops up a message box containing the current epoch time to the millisecond.

You can get the number of milliseconds elapsed in epoch time at your command line with

```
date +%s%N | cut -b1-13
```

So to answer your question, run

```
date +%s%N | cut -b1-13; iceweasel "javascript:alert(Date.now())"
```

Then subtract the number in your terminal from the number in Firefox. This gives you the number of milliseconds Firefox took to open and display some basic javascript.

Sources:

- https://superuser.com/questions/157304/how-can-i-make-firefox-load-javascript-from-the-command-line
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830244/get-current-date-time-in-seconds
- https://serverfault.com/questions/151109/how-do-i-get-current-unix-time-in-milliseconds-using-bash

Answer (score 3):

You can use some tool which can get window id associated with PID, and wait until that window is created. The process id of previously started program is available in `$!` variable.

As an example - using [`wmctrl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl) one can get list of all windows and check if any of them is started by given PID:

```
$ wmctrl -lp
0x00e00003 -1 397    jjmach sawfishpager
0x01200003  6 399    jjmach wmctrl -lp jimmij@jjmach: /proc
0x0180004b  0 655    jjmach emacs@jjmach.jj
0x02800078  7 680    jjmach How to measure Firefox's startup time? - Mozilla Firefox
```

Window id is in first column, and process id in third, so we need to pipe it to `awk` in order to check if given process id has associated window.

```
wmctrl -lp | awk -v pid="$!" '$3==pid{print "Window is created with id "$1}'
```

Now we need to put it in some loop and measure the time until above command will end successfully:

```
firefox & time (while wmctrl -lp | awk -v pid="$!" '$3==pid{exit 1}'; do :; done)
```

So we start firefox and immediately start a loop which in body does nothing (`:`) and ends when `awk` returns non-zero value.

Answer (score 2):

1. start a *listening netcat* in the background
2. call firefox to connect it
3. wait it with a `wait` bash builtin.
4. finally kill everything

   `nc -l 64738 &
   firefox http://127.0.0.1:64738 &
   wait <...yet to be solved that only the nc should be waited for...>
   killall firefox <..yet to be solved to not kill your girlfriends browser>`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the startup time in milliseconds can be found here:

about:telemetry -> Simple Measurements -> firstPaint

Answer (score 1):

You can read the measured startup time from the configuration (about:config):

browser.slowStartup.averageTime